# Проверка чистоты базы данных

Tags: безопасность, postgresql, mysql

Если так получилось, что сервер был взломан, есть ли возможность проверить на основе каких-либо логов или других записей в системе, не производись ли манипуляции (не вносились ли изменения в данные) с базами данных после момента взлома?

Answer (score 2):

вообще-то хорошо бы делать дамп баз данных раз уж у вас есть такой сервер и хранить этот дамп где-то отдельно (процесс можно автоматизировать). К тому же, по умолчанию (по крайней мере, я постоянно отключаю эту опцию) сервер mysql записывает данные ему команды в файлах с именами типа mysql-bin.000001 (храняться по умолчанию в папке хранения данных сервера). Вот если опция не отключена - то можно посмотреть все команды там. Но однако такой режим логирования действий сервера "кушает" место на диске с завидным аппетитом